# How to remove a color (i.e. make it transparent) from a set of SVG images?

Tags: color, batch-processing

[image]

I have a folder with over 600 of such SVG images, and I want to remove all objects with the color value #FFFFE6 in all of them to save space. I can't use a magic wand tool because the color is separated into so many pieces.

How do I remove it?

Comment: You mention the "magic wand", but what software are you using? Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/130666/edit) and provide more information or tag it with the relevant software. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide one of the SVG files? They are effectively text files, and SVG has different ways to assign colors, so this might be an easy or not so easy task to do with a text editor or sed.

Comment: +Billy Kerr any  free software I'm okay with, even trial free, but available for windows 7 or windows 10
+Michael Schumacher Sorry, edited the question (I put a JPEG, because the SVGs are too big). But I won't scan it to text, because I want it to remain hand-written.

Comment: You misunderstood me - SVG files *are* text files, at least in regard to the fact that you can use a text editor (or other text-editing tools) to modify them. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics - these are NOT your typical image file.

Comment: All you need is a text editor to remove something from SVG files.

Comment: +Scott Can you elaborate? I opened the SVG in a text editor and it showed a lot of lines.

Comment: If background and border are raster images embedded in the SVG files, you can use a text processor like [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and create a script to remove the embedded images in all the files. Can you post somewhere (e.g. https://svgur.com/) an example of your SVG files and give us a link?

Comment: link here: https://gofile.io/?c=p9EGHX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on your example, the images are embedded within *<defs></defs>* block of the xml file.

You can try to use [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561946/add-remove-xml-tags-using-a-bash-script) to remove the lines between *<defs>* and *</defs>*.

I'm on a Windows machine at the moment, and I've used a port, **[sed-windows](https://github.com/mbuilov/sed-windows)**, and the following command line get rid of the border of the image (beware that I've used the flag *-i*, that overrides the original file):

```
sed-4.7-x64.exe -i "/<defs>/,/<\/defs>/d" 12.svg
```

After this command, the SVG file is without the border (there are some graphical elements in circles, but I'm not able to understand them). See it [here](https://gofile.io/?c=54QSff).

You can also use another similar command-line tools ([awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe), ...) and arrange a shell script to process all your images.

**Update**

If your original file is a PDF and you need to convert each page in SVG files, you can use a tool based on [Poppler Library](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/). For Windows you can find [here](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/) a compressed file with the compiled binary utility **pdftocairo.exe** which can convert a PDF file to a SVG file.

In your case you simply need a shell script to extract each page and convert it to SVG. For example:

```
pdftocairo.exe -f 10 -l 10 -svg "Madina Mushaf_compressed.pdf" out_10.svg
```

The above command extract page 10 of the PDF and creates a SVG file, which you can process with sed.

Comment: Jazak Allah khayran, where do I put the command you gave me?

Comment: I have them in a PDF (this: ). Can I just do it with just the pdf and then extract the SVGs?

Comment: Script are usually text files with the commands to be executed. The exact syntax of a script depends on your Operating System. For Linux and macOS see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands), for Windows see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259664/the-basics-of-batch-processing-where-should-i-start/19264556).

Comment: PDF structure is different from SVG structure. How have you obtained the SVG you posted? Can you be more precise, please?

Comment: It was first PDF and then I used an online tool from the Internet to convert the PDF to SVG.

Comment: This could add a few more steps. If you can use the engine of the online tool and obtain SVG with the same structure, you can proceed as written above. If you cannot use that engine, you can [convert with Inkscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288065/convert-pdf-to-clean-svg) the PDFs, but the xml files will be different and the above indications should be adapted to the new case. Try, and tell us something about your efforts.

Comment: I want to use PowerShell to remove the raster images from this PDF (https://gofile.io/?c=xQlMia). What should I write in "expression" and "replace"?

Comment: Your PDF file needs to be converted in a lot of SVG files, one for each page you are interested to process. Instead of the online service, you can use the tool I've used in the update of my answer. You don't need PowerShell, yust cmd, the executable programs pdftocairo.exe and sed.exe. And, obviously, you need to write a batch file with all the commands.

Comment: No I wasn't talking about converting, rather about running that command you gave me. I couldn't understand how to get sed.exe to work so I used PowerShell instead. After some searching, I found that I could replace sed with PowerShell using the following command: "get-content somefile.txt | %{$_ -replace "expression","replace"}" and I don't know what to insert in "expression" and "replace"

Comment: I use very seldom PowerShell (sed syntax is simpler), but in my opinion replace isn't the best way (you can replace with "" an expression, but you need to know exactly the content of the expression to be replaced): you want to remove an xml node. This question is more suitable to Stack Overflow. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939930/adding-and-removing-xmlnode-using-powershell), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782335/182588), and also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/117650/deleting-entire-lines-in-a-text-file-based-on-a-partial-string-match-with-window).

Answer (score 1):

SVG Images are created via **text markup** which is actually [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). Much like editing a web page markup, you can learn, evaluate, and edit the text markup of SVG files using a text editor. SVG files are not like other image formats on the web. They are *not* enclosed single elements. They are *text* and are as editable as any text used in web page construction.

Web browsers read an svg file as text and then construct and render an image based upon that *text*. This is very similar to the way editing Cascading Style Sheets for a web page are all done via text edits, but browsers render colors and shapes when they *read* the CSS files.

Open the SVG in a text editor and search for "FFFFE6" you find elements using that color. You can then alter the color in the *text editor* and then save with an .svg suffix... changing the resulting svg file.

[See here for more on editing SVG Markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Getting_Started)

---

It should be noted that while the text structure of SVG files is the way they were *intended* to be usesd. SVG files *can* contain *embedded raster images*. Such embedded raster images will **not** be editable in the text editor. Instead the text editor will show that there is embedded image data rather than directly editable XML markup.

So.... how difficult or easy an SVG image is to edit depends greatly upon how the SVG was constructed initially.

Comment: Jazak Allah khayran for your effort, it appears (because none of their color values was found in the text editor) that the background and border are embedded raster images, so is there a way to remove those?

Comment: If the image is a raster format, they you need to use raster tools ([1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+background+Photoshop)), ([2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+background+Gimp)), to remove something such as that center color in the frame. Chances are the SVG format is most likely unwarranted and resulting in larger file sizes if ti's merely a raster image with an SVG "wrapper".